# Present search input box with Jquery on click, but not submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a search box to display when I click a search icon, the current issue being that when it appears it also submits a search. How can I get it to make the search box appear but not submit the search at that point, this only obviosly comes when the enter something in the search box and click on submit.

https://jsfiddle.net/9twxq1Lq/1/

```
<form class="search" method="post" action="/search">
    <input type="text" name="criteria" placeholder="Search Box">
    <button>
        <i class="icons icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="sr">Search Box</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: give return false, where you want to restrict submit form

Comment: inside the onclick of the button in your javascript add event.preventDefault(); this prevents the button from doing its default behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly you should add a `type="button"` attribute to the `button` to stop it submitting the form. Then you should attach the event handler to the button, not the icon inside it. Finally you need to make sure jQuery is included in your page, as it wasn't part of the fiddle. Try this:

```js
$('.search-button').click(function() {
  $('.search input').toggle();
});
```

```css
.search input {
  background-color: #FDFDFC;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: .9em;
  padding: .8em 1em .7em;
  color: #252424;
}
.search input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="search" method="post" action="/search">
  <input type="text" name="criteria" placeholder="Search Box">
  <button type="button" class="search-button">
    <i class="icons icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <span class="sr">Search Box</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is looking spot on, and works great. But when my search box appears  and I type some text I can't get the search to submit - tried it live in the browser too with no search submit working as yet. In this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9twxq1Lq/1/ in its raw form,it is performing the search function I need.

Comment: You would need to use a separate button to submit the form in that case - one `type="button"` to show the form, and another `type="submit"` in the form to perform the search. It would be possible to do it with a single button, but you'd need to use some JS logic to determine the intended function (ie. show or submit) and this would also mean that the search input could not be hidden again.

Comment: Any advice on getting this to submit too - would it just be a case of changing the type to submit from button after it has been clicked(jquery actioned)?

Comment: A bit more complicated than that - you'd need to hook to the `submit` event of the form and block the submission depending on the state of the input: https://jsfiddle.net/t83zpb2m/. As I mentioned though, doing it this way means you cannot hide the search input again

Comment: Answer ticked, spot on - absolutely perfect. Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 2):

A `button` is considered as a `submit` button if no `type` is defined in a form. If you don't want to submit the form use `<button type="button">`.

This will tell the browser not to submit the form if button is clicked. Alternatively, you can use JavaScript to prevent submitting the form if enter is hit.